# Vaadin Table - AddNestedContainerProperty

Tags: java, vaadin, jpa-2.0, vaadin7, nested-properties

```
public class LocationBasedRole extends AbstractEntity{
    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Role> roles=new HashSet<Role>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Location> locations=new HashSet<Location>();
}


public class Role extends AbstractEntity{
    private String name;
}


public class Location extends AbstractEntity{
    private String location;
}
```

I have an entity named locationBasedRole which has 2 properties named roles and locations. Both roles and locations have a @ManyToMany relation with locationBasedRole.
Now I want to have one property of each in a Vaadin Table. 
It should be something like this,

```
public class UserForm extends OgsAbstractForm<User>{

    MTable<LocationBasedRole> locationBasedRoleTable = new MTable<LocationBasedRole>().withHeight("100%").withWidth("100%");


    @Override
    protected Component createContent() {

        Set<LocationBasedRole> lbRoles=new HashSet<LocationBasedRole>();
        roles.addAll(locationBasedRoleFasade.findAll());

        BeanItemContainer<LocationBasedRole> bean=new BeanItemContainer<LocationBasedRole>(LocationBasedRole.class);

        //It returns an error on the next both lines and I know the reason, but don't know how to solve it.
        // If it was no ManyToMany relation and the properties weren't a collection, it would work
        bean.addNestedContainerProperty("roles.name");
        bean.addNestedContainerProperty("locations.location");

        bean.removeContainerProperty("persistent");
        bean.removeContainerProperty("id");

        bean.addAll(lbRoles);

        locationBasedRoleTable.setContainerDataSource(bean);

        return new VerticalLayout(locationBasedRoleTable);
    }
}
```

When I remove the properties from the NestedContainerProperties it shows me at least something in the table.

```
bean.addNestedContainerProperty("roles");
bean.addNestedContainerProperty("locations");
```

I could use any help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's an MTable?

Comment: @Jay, I'm using Vitrin library for Vaadin, here you can read more about it, https://vaadin.com/directory/component/viritin

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand your question right, you want to have the Collections of your BeanItemContainer-Entity displayed in one column each?

I see two possibilities for that.

**Option 1 - use a wrapper class for your `Set`s and use `addNestedContainerBean`**

One possibility would be to not use `Set`s inside your `LocationBasedRole` but to use a wrapper class that extends `HashSet`.
Then you could use the `addNestedContainerBean` method.

I created a small example with the BeanItemContainer-Entity `Team`

```
public class Team {

    private String teamName;
    private Members teamMembers;

    public String getTeamName() {
        return teamName;
    }

    public void setTeamName(String teamName) {
        this.teamName = teamName;
    }

    public Members getTeamMembers() {
        return teamMembers;
    }

    public void setTeamMembers(Members teamMembers) {
        this.teamMembers = teamMembers;
    }
}
```

Which consists of a name and teamMembers. The latter is of type `Members`:

```
public class Members extends HashSet<TeamMember> {

    public String getMembers() {
        return this.stream()
                .map(member -> member.getFirstName() + " " + member.getLastName())
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
    }

}
```

Which is a simple wrapper for the `Set` that contains instances of `TeamMember`:

```
public class TeamMember {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Integer age;

    // getters and setters
}
```

As you can see in the `Members` class, there is a method `getMembers` which returns a String, containing a comma separated list of the team members names.

If we now use `addNestedContainerBean("teamMembers")` Vaadin tries to display all properties contained in the class `Members`. Vaadin will think getMembers is a getter for a String property called members and so generate a column for it.

Vaadin will also display a column "empty" because it will find the `isEmpty` method of `Set` and think `empty` is a property to display in a column. So we tell Vaadin to remove that column.

The final code of my example looks like:

```
protected Component createContent() {

        Set<Team> teams=new HashSet<>();
        for (int teamCounter = 0; teamCounter < 5; teamCounter++) {
            Team team = createTeam();
            addMembersToTeam(5, team);
            teams.add(team);
        }

        BeanItemContainer<Team> bean=new BeanItemContainer<>(Team.class);

        bean.addNestedContainerBean("teamMembers");
        bean.removeContainerProperty("teamMembers.empty");

        bean.addAll(teams);

        teamTable.setContainerDataSource(bean);

        return new VerticalLayout(teamTable);
    }
```

The result looks like:

[image: Option 1]

**Option 2 - create fake getters and use `addNestedContainerProperty`**

The only thing you have to do for this is extend your BeanItemContainer-Entity (`LocationBasedRole`) and create a fake getter for each `Set` you want to be displayed in a column. In your example those two fake getters could be `public String getTheRoles()` and `public String getTheLocations()`. Then you can use `bean.addNestedContainerProperty("theRoles")` and `bean.addNestedContainerProperty("theLocations")`.

In my example my `TeamMember` class (the counterpart to your `Role` / `Location` classes) would still look like in the option above:

```
 public class TeamMember {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Integer age;

    // getters and setters
}
```

And my `Team` class (your `LocationBasedRole`) would look like:

```
public class Team {

    private String teamName;
    private Set<TeamMember> teamMembers;

    public String getTeamName() {
        return teamName;
    }

    public void setTeamName(String teamName) {
        this.teamName = teamName;
    }

    public Set<TeamMember> getTeamMembers() {
        return teamMembers;
    }

    public void setTeamMembers(Set<TeamMember> teamMembers) {
        this.teamMembers = teamMembers;
    }

    public String getMembers() {
        if (teamMembers != null) {
            return teamMembers.stream()
                    .map(member -> member.getFirstName() + " " + member.getLastName())
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
        } else {
            return "No members";
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can tell vaadin to add the (not existing) property "members" and Vaadin will find the getter `getMembers` and use this for generating the column. We also have to tell vaadin not to display the original "teamMembers" property. So the final code is:

```
protected Component createContent() {

    Set<Team> teams=new HashSet<>();
    for (int teamCounter = 0; teamCounter < 5; teamCounter++) {
        Team team = createTeam();
        addMembersToTeam(5, team);
        teams.add(team);
    }

    BeanItemContainer<Team> bean=new BeanItemContainer<>(Team.class);

    bean.addNestedContainerProperty("members");
    bean.removeContainerProperty("teamMembers");

    bean.addAll(teams);

    teamTable.setContainerDataSource(bean);

    return new VerticalLayout(teamTable);
}
```

and the result looks like:

[image: option 2]

Comment: Tnx @codinghaus, but it's not what I want. I want to have 2 columns in my table, one shows the roles.name and the other must show the locations.location. They have a manytomany relation with LocationsBaseRole and they will be initialized LAZY.

Comment: I thought your main issue was how to display properties (roles.name and locations.location) of sets (roles/locations) in single columns (1 column for roles.name and 1 column for locations.location). Did I understand it wrong? Bc in my proposed options I describe how to solve this. You have LoctionBasedRoles with sets of locations/roles, I have Teams with set of TeamMembers. I created 1 column, in which the name property of each teammember is displayed. Why can't you apply that for your role and location sets? The only difference I see is LAZY, but that is hibernate/jpa related and not vaadin.